# Add-in SelectChange() event

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I created an Add-in that has a user form. So in this user form I have display info from the selected cell, so when I add the SelectChange() event it works, but when I create the Add-in version it doesn't work because the add in "has its own workbook", so the select change is working in the Add-in file and not in the active workbook or worksheet... so, am I right? is there a way to use a SelectChange() event in an Add-in that reads the info from the active sheet?

Comment: You need application events: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: @Rory thanks for your answer, that really solved all of my problems!

Answer (score 0):

something like this, not fully tested

```
Public WithEvents objEXCEL As Excel.Application
Public WithEvents objWB As Excel.Workbook

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set objEXCEL = Application
    Set objWB = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub objEXCEL_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Set objEXCEL = Application
    Set objWB = Wb
End Sub

Private Sub objWS_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.Address
End Sub
```